# Limit bucket access based on user in minio

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I am busy setting up minio for the first time and I would like to limit each user so that they can only see buckets they create, or public buckets.

The idea being that `admin` can see all buckets, but `user1` can only see buckets created by `user1`, etc.

Is this possible?

I know that using `mc policy` I can set a buckets access policy to `none, download, upload, public`. To the best of my knowledge, setting the policy to `none` will require authenticated access to a bucket - but this will allow any authenticated user which is not what I want.

I have come across this ticket on github - https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/6811

This will create a user policy that limits the users access to a single bucket. The provided example does not allow the user list buckets (private and self created), create new buckets, etc. This user can *only* access the bucket listed in the policy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question with feedback from the minio team

> No it is not possible, we do something similar to what AWS does, user
>   is not tied to buckets . Buckets exist for all users you just
>   selectively give them access.